# join() method in multiprocessing with input and output Queue()

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

I have a SOMETIMES working piece of code:

```
def my_map2(func, iterable, processes=None):
    ''' FASTER THAN mp.Pool() - NOT '''
    import multiprocessing as mp    # Load multiprocessing library
    mp.freeze_support()
    if (processes == None):
        processes = mp.cpu_count()  # Set maximum number of cores?
    L = len(iterable)
    iter2 = zip(iterable,range(L))
    IN = mp.Queue()
    for x in iter2:
        IN.put(x)
    OUT = mp.Queue()                # = mp.JoinableQueue() Q3
    lock = mp.Lock() # Q2
    def target_fun(IN, OUT):
        while not IN.empty():
            inp = IN.get()
            out = (inp[0],func(inp[1]))
            with lock: # Q2
                OUT.put(out)
    proc = [mp.Process(target=target_fun, args=(IN, OUT,)) for x in range(processes)]
    for p in proc: p.start()                # Run proc
    for p in proc: p.join()                 # Exit the completed proc Q1
    results = [OUT.get() for p in range(L)] # Get Results Back        Q1
    results.sort()                          # Sort
    return( [r[1] for r in results] )


import time
def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.1);
    return(x)

res = my_map2(f,range(100))
```

Questions:

1. join() called before collecting from the queue. Why does this code work at all? join() is invoked before before Queue is empty so it should deadlock according to documentation:

   > any Queue that a Process has put data on must be drained prior to joining the processes which have put data there: otherwise, you’ll get a deadlock.
   >   However if 2 lines marked with 'Q1' are swapped then we should run into an issue "getting from an empty queue", but both variants seem to SOMETIMES work...
2. If I remove the Lock() (edit 2 lines with Q2) it does get a deadlock. Why now?

   > Queues are thread and process safe. When using multiple processes, one generally uses message passing for communication between processes and avoids having to use any synchronization primitives like locks. (talking about pipes and queues)
3. JoinableQueue. If I try using it it does not work. I tried all:

   > If you use JoinableQueue then you must call JoinableQueue.task_done().
   >   If a child process has put items on a queue (and it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread()), then that process will not terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the pipe.

Question 3 is: So what is an actual difference between Normal and Joinable queue? Does it mean that you can terminate child that has put something on a normal Queue at any time? I thought only manager processes work like this...
Also, so how do you correctly use both Queues?

I have read library reference, quite a few tutorials and stack overflow posts, but does anybody really understand how this works? (Talking about join(), different Queue types, when is the lock needed and accurate understanding of processes behind)

Comment: I'm not going to answer all your questions, but I can see that you have a race in `target_fun()` between `IN.empty()` and `IN.get()` - i.e. if process A gets `False` from `IN.empty()` but then another process gets the last object from `IN.get()` before process A can, you could end up with `out` in process A being undefined.

Comment: I've never seen a lock used that way, I don't think that works. You need pass the lock into the Processes, and use my_lock.acquire() and my_lock.release(). However, when using a queue, I don't think you need to use a lock at all. For this code, you should simplify and just map the inerrable to a Pool. W.r.t. Q1, why not just empty the queue first, or do you have more of a philosophical question?

Comment: Q1 is simply "why .join() works when it Queue is not emptied while it should not?". Locks do work that way - acquire and release do not change anything" An example with Value lock: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects. Anyways, lock is not really needed here at all - thus disregard question 2. Regarding Pool - the whole idea is to make my own to understand what is going on rather than use wrappers.

Comment: pourhaus. You are right - problems are caused in there.